# Pinning a NSTableColumn so that it does not scroll horizontally?

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, nsscrollview, nstablecolumn

I'm trying to figure out a way to have a `NSTableColumn` be pinned to the left side of my `NSTableView`. What I have been thinking of is putting two `NSTableView`'s side by side, where the first one contains the 'pinned' column and the second on contains the dynamic data. Setting the first table to disable horizontal scrolling, then detecting when either table is scrolled vertically and keeping the two in sync.

What I'm wondering, is if anyone else has any experience in doing something similar? I don't want to re-invent the wheel if its already been done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats exactly what I did. Two `NSTableView`'s directly beside each other. The first I subclassed the `NSScrollView` and modified the scroll events to do nothing. The second I subclassed again the `NSScrollView` and modified the scroll events to cause the header to mirror it. Works great.